# My images won't show

Tags: javascript

My images won't show up when I am trying to load up this page! I am trying to make a traffic light sequence (UK) that shows up with all the colours when the change lights button is pressed!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>

<h1><u><b>Changing Traffic Lights</b></u><h1>

<button type="button" onClick="changeLights()"> Change Lights </button>    <!-- Creates a button to change the lights with -->

<img id ="trafficlight" src="red.jpg"></img>   <!-- Creates the first visible image on the page and gives it an ID so it can be called up later -->

<script>

var trafficlights = ["red-amber.jpg","green.jpg","amber.jpg","red.jpg"]  //creates an array for the lights

var currentlight = 0 //Creates a counter variable

function changeLights () {         //Calls up a function and designs it
    document.getElementById("trafficlight").src=trafficlights[currentlight]  //Calls up the image and enables it to be changed
    currentlight=currentlight+1   //Adds one to the counter
    if (currentlight>3){
        currentlight=0
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do any images show up? is your path to source correct? are the images actually available? what happens if you just display an image without trying to cycle through them?

Comment: Also, check out your `if` statement because it is causing your button to toggle from the second click on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you open the developer tools, you'll see the images can't be fetched and get a 404 error, showing a wrong path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. But you must have a problem with your **image source paths**. Because this works correctly when I change the images to something remote like lorempixel.

Working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d8medaeo/1/).

Try to fix the image paths in your JS. Good luck.

```
var trafficlights = ["http://lorempixel.com/100/100","http://lorempixel.com/100/90","http://lorempixel.com/100/100","http://lorempixel.com/100/110"]
```